# Webshopapps_Productmatrix vs Webshopapps_Matrixrate

Tags: magento-1, extensions

I have inherited a couple of old Magento 1 sites and there is a difference between the WebShopApps Matrix Rate extensions.  One shows as `Webshopapps_Matrixrate` and the other shows as `Webshopapps_Productmatrix`.

1. Are these the same extension?
2. `Webshopapps_Matrixrate` an updated version of `Webshopapps_Productmatrix`

I can't find any information on this on the WebShopApps site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen these

https://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-1-extensions.html

Ultimate

https://webshopapps.com/us/magento-1-extensions/wsa-standalone/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html

Free

https://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-1-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

Paid

https://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-1-extensions/wsa-standalone/premium-matrixrate-shipping-extension.html

So product is ultimate edition if you like